# Can some slack permissions give apps access to all private and direct messages?

Tags: slack, slackbot, slack-integration

Some students have added some apps to slack that have the following permissions:

channels:history
View messages and other content in a user’s public and private channels

groups:history
View messages and other content in a user’s public and private channels

im:history
View messages and other content in a user’s direct messages

I would like to know how exactly these apps can be used and if they can be used to read other student's private messages by the students who added them so I can report to my university. I also want to know how can we find out if our private messages were compromised.